# Es posible hostear con github pages un proyecto en laravel?

Tags: laravel, github

Buenas tardes quería saber si era posible poder hostear con github pages un proyecto hecho en Laravel, y si es asi, si es que me podían guiar en como hacerlo.

Comment: No es posible, te recomiendo leas aqui: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#about-github-pages

Comment: [GitHub Pages es un servicio de alojamiento de sitios estáticos que toma archivos HTML, CSS y JavaScript directamente de un repositorio en GitHub.](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=es&text=GitHub%20Pages%20is%20a%20static%20site%20hosting%20service%20that%20takes%20HTML%2C%20CSS%2C%20and%20JavaScript%20files%20straight%20from%20a%20repository%20on%20GitHub&op=translate)

Answer (score 2):

en Laravel.io se tocó este tema hace un tiempo, e indicaron que GitHub Pages sirve solo páginas estáticas, por ende no procesa nada del lado del servidor. Por lo tanto, no podrías servir un proyecto que trabaje con el framework Laravel.

Esto se confirma además en la documentación de Github Pages, donde te indica que sirve para servir páginas estáticas con HTML, CSS y JS.

[GitHub Pages is a static site hosting service that takes HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages)